# How to dismiss a AlertDialog after some codes in android studio

Tags: android, dialog, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

I wrote this code :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SketchActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Rendering");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    alertDialog.show();
```

then I have a Switch like this:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageViewSketch1:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch2:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 2);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch3:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 3);
            break;
}
```

and finally I have :

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

But my problem is here that alertDialog do not show and user can not see alertDialog.

Comment: Can you show where are you dismissing the dialog? Maybe you are showing it and then dismissing without any conditions.

Comment: I think, you should use handler as well.

Comment: First I show alertDialog, Then run Switch Case code and finally dismiss the alertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Your alert dialog is showing, but it's too fast you can't rally see it because the switch function finishes quickly.

You would need to add some delay before calling `allertDialog.dismiss()`

Since your code is in Java, you could do something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(() -> allertDialog.dismiss(), 2000);  // 2 seconds
```

Your updated code with a ProgressDialog, instead of an AlertDialog should look like this:

```
public void runMyFunc(View v)
{

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SketchActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Rendering");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show()
    
    Bitmap bmp;

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageViewSketch1:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch2:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 2);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch3:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 3);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch4:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 4);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch5:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 5);
            break;
    }
    
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalImage.cols(), finalImage.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(finalImage, bmp);
    imageSketch.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(() -> progressDialog.dismiss(), 2000);  // 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear, but some of my Switch Case codes get several seconds. I don't know why first Run alertDialog.dismiss(); and then Run my Switch Case !!!

Comment: I don't know why first run my Switch Case codes and then alertDialog.show() and alertDialog.dismiss() run ?!?!

Comment: First construct and show your dialog, then create the handler and finally have your switch.

Comment: I have that problem yet ! these solutions did not solve my problem

Comment: Can you post your updated code so we know what you have so far. Then we can move from there.

Comment: I added my code below

Comment: I don't see any handler with a delay in your new code, as I've suggested above. I also don't see progressDialog.show(). I've updated my answer to reflect your changes.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code :

```
    public void runMyFunc(View v)
{

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SketchActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Rendering");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    Bitmap bmp;

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageViewSketch1:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch2:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 2);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch3:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 3);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch4:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 4);
            break;
        case R.id.imageViewSketch5:
            finalImage = new ImageAction().doFilter(originalImage, 5);
            break;
    }
    
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalImage.cols(), finalImage.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(finalImage, bmp);
    imageSketch.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: ProgressDialog is deprecated. Use its alternative

Comment: What is ProgressDialog  alternative  ?!

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem yet
Due to last answer I by *Filip Petrovski* I added handler.postDelayed after switch case but this made other problem :
first switch case code run and then my progress dialog appear and then after 2 seconds disappear, but I want my progress dialog appear before switch case.
I don't know why my progress dialog appear after run the switch case code !!!!

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather appears to be a follow up question.